# Can't get quokka.js working with TypeScript 5.x and ES Decorators

Tags: javascript, typescript, decorator, typescript-decorator, quokka.js

I'm trying to run quokka.js in VSCode against a simple TypeScript file with the following decorator:

```
function message<Input extends new (...args: any) => any>(msg: string) {
    return function (value: Input, context: ClassDecoratorContext) {
    // remaining code removed for brevity...
```

Here is the consuming class:

```
@message("Hello from the employee class")
export class Employee {
    public firstName: string;
```

So a couple of notes, this code **does** transpile using the `tsc` command, and the resulting transpiled `.js` file *does work* with quokka.js. However, if I run quokka.js on the TypeScript file itself (start on current file), quokka will fail with the following:

> ​​​​​Quokka 'Decorators.ts' (node: v18.16.0, **TypeScript: v5.3.3**)​​​​
> Failed to instrument scripts/typescript/Advanced/Decorators.js    47 |
> var ESDecorators;    48 | (function (ESDecorators) {
>
> > 49 |     **@message**("Hello from the employee class") 
> > |     ^ **SyntaxError: Unexpected character '@'** (49:4)

Notice it's using TypeScript 5.3.3 shown in the error message which *does* work with ES Decorators. In fact I've used the following quokka.js configuration in package.json to ensure it's using this version locally installed, and not using swc, babel, or anything else:

```
  "quokka": { 
    "ts": {
      "compiler": "typescript",
      "swc": false
    }
  }
```

With TypeScript 5.x+, you also don't need the legacy experimentalDecorators flags turned on so the following is commented out in tsconfig.json:

```
// "experimentalDecorators": true,
// "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
```

So just to level set, the code *works*, transpiles with the TypeScript compiler, and valid JavaScript is omitted. That indicates a syntactically correct code sample. The problem is *only* with quokka.js running the TypeScript file directly. Even though it's using TypeScript 5.3.3 as displayed in the error, it cant understand the `@` synatax of Decorators. My research has yielded nothing, and this should work. What do I need to do please to make this ES Decorator code work while running quokka.js?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out and it was not `quokka` specific but rather with the TypeScript configuration. Ironically `esnext` even though supposed to point to the latest and greatest spec, actually has this nuance and can't be run as-is:

*"using any new JavaScript features that are not yet officially part of an ECMAScript standard, but are in a draft stage (i.e. Stage 3 Decorators), those features will be left as is"*

Therefore if I use the older `es2018` the decorators work as expected. Per the behavior:

*"Any newer JavaScript features used in your TypeScript code that are not part of ECMAScript 2016 will be transpiled down to equivalent ECMAScript 2018 syntax"*

In this case the decorators are transpiled and work correctly so long as it can be transpiled to compatible JS that will run today.

Comment: It's not ironic if you consider that `"target"` specifies the output JS which will be generated from the TS source code. The later the target the less transformation. esnext as a target says not to transform syntax if it is stage 3 or later in the latest ECMAScript version. By definition, esnext is a moving target. Decorators are now stage 3 and thus are no longer transformed by the latest TS which takes their promotion into account